# How do I refer to a range in another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

*Sheet 1* has numeric values in the `B` column. I'd like to sum them into a single value within *Sheet 2*, preferably without having to copy them individually first.

[According to the docs](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/75943?hl=en), I can copy a single value by doing this:

```
=Sheet1!B1
```

And that works great! But I'm looking to do a little more -- something like this:

```
=SUM(Sheet1!B1:Sheet1!B5)
```

Unfortunately, when I use *that* formula, I get `#ERROR!` and it says "Formula Parse Error."
How can I refer to a *range* in another sheet, not just a single cell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should refer to the sheet name only once, so:

```
=SUM(Sheet1!B1:B5)
```

returns the sum of the range `B1:B5` in `Sheet1`.